# mysql error 1062 'duplicate entry' when restoring backup

Tags: debian-lenny, mysql, mysql5

Sorry, I seen similar threads but I still couldn't find it addressing my issue plus, I needed some more info on this.

**Requirement:** To create an exact replica 'db4' of an existing DB 'db3'.

**Procedure followed:**

- mysqldump -uuser -ppass db3 > db3.sql (size is 6G)
- mysql -uuser -ppass db4 < db3.sql (db4 was a newly created blank database)

The 2nd step throws in the error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 5524: Duplicate entry '600806' for key 1"
```

I ran the 2nd step  again with --force. The restore completed but with 2 additional similar errors:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 6309: Duplicate entry '187694' for key 1    
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 6572: Duplicate entry '1567400' for key 1
```

On completion when I queried certain tables of db4 database, I was able to see missing records.

**Question:**

1. Does this indicate a corrupted/problematic db3 database?
2. How to proceed to create a 'consistent/working' replica (db4) of db3?

Thanks,

Comment: My first thought is a race condition during the dump but I'm not sure if that's possible.  (It certainly shouldn't be if you are using MyISAM.)  You might want to try the dump again with `--lock-all-tables`.  The mysql commands `check table` and `repair table` can test for corruption of db3.

Comment: @Ladadadada, I did mysqldupm with --lock-all-tables. Restoring this backup to a blank DB makes it exit again with "Duplicate entry '600806' for key 1" error. Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: Could you show us the table schema for the table concerned? What is the engine in use (i.e. MyISAM or InnoDB or..?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various reasons where such "duplicates" may occur:

- your data is toast.
- an application INSERTed using the auto-increment, but later ran an UPDATE to 
  manually modify the identity to a different, probably existing value. This
  sometimes occurs with application developers who are sorting "by ID" and want 
  to "fix the sorting" (by actually breaking consistency).
- a variation of the second issue happens by folks who later add a "unique" constraint,
  after non-unique records have been inserted.

The error messages do refer to the first key, which in most database schemas is the first value. Take a look at the raw dump output, particularly the INSERT statements and check for

> `INSERT INTO ... values (0,...`

Scan around the line numbers of the mysql dump given in the error messages.

Example of what kind of mysqldump I'm expecting:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id,bar,baz) values (1,2,3);
INSERT INTO foo (id,bar,baz) values (0,4,5);
INSERT INTO foo (id,bar,baz) values (2,6,7);
```

In a "normal" INSERT-statement on an auto-increment field, the value "0" specifies to auto-increment the field and so shouldn't show up in a database SQL dump where an auto-increment field is being used. By re-loading the database via a SQL dump, your dump asks the SQL server to increment the current field value by one and insert that ID. If someone manually UPDATEd the identity to zero after INSERTing the record, your MySQL Dump will include this strange id as well.

If you're replaying this dump into an empty table, this would try to create the following records:

```
1,2,3
2,4,5
2,6,7
```

As the "id" field has been set to unique autoincrement, the second INSERT will create a "wrong" record (expected: 0,4,5; actual: 2,4,5) which conflicts with the following record (id=2) and as a result gives the error message.

In a variation of this, someone "manually" updated the identity to an already existing value and later change the record to be "unique". Changing a record type to unique doesn't make MySQL re-validate if the current data matches the requirement, hence the delayed error.
This variation may create a dump like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id,bar,baz) values (1,2,3);
INSERT INTO foo (id,bar,baz) values (1,4,5);
INSERT INTO foo (id,bar,baz) values (2,6,7);
```

Trying to insert the second line will fail due to the unique constraint.

In both cases, using "--force" only ignores the "conflicting" line and continues importing. The "conflicting" lines will be missing, but probably the lines leading to this conflict will be there (but with a wrong id record).

Please do check your database dump if my idea matches your problem.
If that's the case, here are two workarounds to "make it work":

- import data in two steps, first only the schema, later the data.
  Remove the unique constraints from your schema before importing the data,
  later again do add the unique constraints ("ALTER TABLE ... add unique...").
- force-import schema and all data, resulting in "different" constraint issues.
  Manually check which records are correct and re-assign the wrong ones to
  their original value.

Example for the later issue:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass --execute "SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; source db3.sql" db4
```

This does force to import all conflicting records, even violating any real unique constraints. After import, you'll have multiple entries for those three records (600806, 187694 and 1567400), and you'll have to manually sort out which are the correct ones by checking your dump, which of those "duplicates" did result in the conflict and manually  update the wrong records "back" to zero (or whatever the conflicting line in the dump said).

In both scenarios, your data still violates the given schema: your schema says data to be unique, but it isn't. In the long run, the data needs to be fixed on application level.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, check to see whether the rows in question exist in that state in the original database.

Chances are, what happened is one of the following:

- The column/field in question wasn't unique at one point, but was altered later on.
- This is a slave database that you are dumping, and there have been some binlog replays at some point, and potential duplicate keys were inserted
- Bad SQL statement or import of commands resulted in duplicate entries.

If there are only 3 rows that are showing the problem, correct the key field for them, if possible, perform a dump and import of that instance and see if the error doesn't present itself again. I'm guessing, it should go away.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

So I came across this issue after one of our replication servers went into an inconsistent state. We couldn't get it back on line with a quick fix and decided to reinitialize the replication with a new backup.

The question stated above is not the same problem but does return the same error therefore I decided to add this answer in case other people are looking for it.

It is also an exact duplicate of this question on [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31598/mysql-duplicate-entry-error-1062-when-restoring-backup) but because this question has a higher ranking in (my) Google results I'm also posting it here.

**What we did**

We deleted all our databases on the instance with MySQL Workbench, I restarted the instance and double checked that there where no databases left on the instance.
On the master server we had already started creating a new backup with the script we always use.

Then once the backup was on the failed server we started the import and after a couple of hours it had imported most of the data and failed with these kinds of errors:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line XXX: Duplicate entry 'dbName-tblName' for key 'PRIMARY'
Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

We thought okay, maybe something went wrong when creating the backup, I checked out the data in the backup but couldn't find anything wrong. We retried all the steps again just to be sure we didn't miss anything but unfortunately there was no cigar..

**The actual problem**

The error that is displayed is not the actual insert of the data but the creation of an index. This is why the data was inserted without a problem (we checked) but still generated an error. Apparently deleting all the tables is not sufficient, index data still exists on the server (this might be due to a change in MySQL 5.6 as we never had this problem before). And because the import of these index is somewhere in the middle of the import file the rest of the data didn't get imported.

**The fix**

We deleted the ibdata1 file and all the innodb_index_stats and innodb_table_stats files in the mysql database folder and then started the instance. 
MySQL will then tell you that some system tables are missing 
[you can find more info on that here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/cannot-open-table-mysql-innodb-index-stats)

This solved our issue and our server is now replicating as expected.

Hopefully this save some hours for someone somewhere :)